# Spring security role based authorisation is not working

Tags: java, spring, security

I have a web service and I need to use a role based authorisation, I have 3 roles and all go them doesn't work here is a code of my security configuration `@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthConfig {

```
@Bean
public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector() {
    return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
}
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new CustomUserDetailsService();
}


@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(
            auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/api/student/**").hasAnyAuthority("STUDENT","ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/api/teacher/**").hasAnyAuthority("TEACHER","ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
    return config.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

}

and here is an example of my student service

@Service
public class StudentService {

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private AssessmentItemRepository assessmentItemRepository;


public List<StudentGradeDTO> getStudentGrades(Long studentId) {
    User student = userRepository.findById(studentId).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Student not found"));
    List<Subject> enrolledSubjects = student.getEnrolledSubjects();

    List<StudentGradeDTO> studentGrades = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Subject subject : enrolledSubjects) {
        List<AssessmentItem> assessments = assessmentItemRepository.findBySubjectAndStudent(subject, student);
        for (AssessmentItem assessment : assessments) {
            StudentGradeDTO gradeDTO = new StudentGradeDTO();
            gradeDTO.setSubjectName(subject.getName());
            gradeDTO.setType(assessment.getType());
            gradeDTO.setExaminerName(assessment.getExaminerName());
            gradeDTO.setGrade(assessment.getGrade());
            gradeDTO.setExamDate(assessment.getExamDate());

            studentGrades.add(gradeDTO);
        }
    }

    return studentGrades;
}




public List<AssessmentItem> getUpcomingExamsForStudent(Long studentId) {
    User student = userRepository.findById(studentId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Student not found"));

    List<AssessmentItem> upcomingExams = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    for (Subject subject : student.getEnrolledSubjects()) {
        List<AssessmentItem> exams = assessmentItemRepository.findBySubjectAndTypeAndExamDateAfter(
                subject, "Exam", currentDateTime);
        upcomingExams.addAll(exams);
    }

    return upcomingExams;
}
```

}

student controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/student")
public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/grades/{studentId}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<StudentGradeDTO>> getStudentGrades(@PathVariable Long studentId) {
        List<StudentGradeDTO> studentGrades = studentService.getStudentGrades(studentId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(studentGrades);
    }
    @GetMapping("/upcoming-exams/{studentId}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<AssessmentItem>> getUpcomingExams(@PathVariable Long studentId) {
        List<AssessmentItem> upcomingExams = studentService.getUpcomingExamsForStudent(studentId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(upcomingExams);
    }
```

and when I send a request to get a marks for example, I put in header authorisation "Bearer + token", but I get a 401 status and here s a debug from spring
2023-12-08T15:17:49.468+02:00 DEBUG 39093 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/student/grades/1
2023-12-08T15:17:49.491+02:00 DEBUG 39093 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-12-08T15:17:49.513+02:00 DEBUG 39093 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/api/student/grades/1?continue to session
2023-12-08T15:17:49.514+02:00 DEBUG 39093 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2023-12-08T15:17:49.514+02:00 DEBUG 39093 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@78ae146f
2023-12-08T15:17:49.516+02:00 DEBUG 39093 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-12-08T15:17:49.520+02:00 DEBUG 39093 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-12-08T15:17:49.523+02:00 DEBUG 39093 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/error?continue to session
2023-12-08T15:17:49.523+02:00 DEBUG 39093 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2023-12-08T15:17:49.523+02:00 DEBUG 39093 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@78ae146f

and I put role in jwt

```
@Component
public class JwtService {

    public static final String SECRET = "5367566B59703373367639792F423F4528482B4D6251655468576D5A71347437";

    public void validateToken(final String token) {
        parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSignKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
    }

    public String generateToken(String email, UserRole role) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("role", role);
        return createToken(claims, email);
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String userName) {
        return builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(userName)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 30))
                .signWith(getSignKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
    }

    private Key getSignKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

}
```

so anyone knows what is the problem? with permitAll() everything of course is working, but I need to use the roles